# How to open Instagram Posting Screen in Android?

Tags: instagram

Is there something equivalent to `instagram://camera` in Android like in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as I know there are not somthing equivalent but you can post photo(or video, just change a little bit) directly to instagram posting dialog:

```java
public void postInstagramPhoto(File photo, String message, OnPostingCompleteListener onPostingCompleteListener) {
    String instagramPackage = "com.instagram.android";
    String errorMessage = "You should install Instagram app first";
    if(isPackageInstalled(instagramPackage, getActivity())){
        Intent normalIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        normalIntent.setType("image/*");
        normalIntent.setPackage(instagramPackage);
        File media = new File(photo.getAbsolutePath());
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media);
        normalIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        normalIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        getActivity().startActivity(normalIntent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Install Instagram first.", Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

you can check other popular methods from [asne-instagram here](https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE/blob/master/instagram/src/main/java/com/github/gorbin/asne/instagram/InstagramSocialNetwork.java)

or maybe if you need to add more social networks [check this](https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE)